# does twing.include.statement returns a multilanguage template in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

MyBundle:SayHello.html.twing:

```
{% trans %}Hello world{% endtrans %}
```

From another *.html.twing:

```
{{ include('MyBundle:SayHello.html.twing') }}
```

---

Does "{{ include('MyBundle:SayHello.html.twing') }}" returns the variables translated  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, your variables will be translated, but you need to set **translation_domain** in *MyBundle:SayHello.html.twig*.

And check out please the way you name your templates. I think you have a typo in "*.twig"